# É possível deixar cada link da categoria de uma cor no wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Oi! Estou tentando colorir o background do link de cada categoria, deixando cada um de uma cor, mas queria que estilizasse APENAS os links da categorias na página inicial, não quero alterar o style na pagina das categorias. É algo assim que estou tentando fazer:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Queria saber se é possível fazer isso e se poderiam me ajuda.
Esse é o meu código até agora:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="artigo">
<div class="post-header"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'large'); ?></div> 

<div class="icons-categ"><?php the_category('') ?></div>
</div>



<?php endwhile?>    <?php else: ?>    <?php endif; ?>   

</div>
```

Esse é o código das categorias que tenho no css, mas ele parece que não funciona:

```
.category-noticias .icons-categ {
    background: #e07737;
    color:#fff;
}

.category-celebridades .icons-categ {
    background: #1865e4;
    color:#fff;
}

.category-musicas .icons-categ {
    background: #aa0909;
    color:#fff;
}

.category-filmes .icons-categ {
    background: #b6e037;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Obs: estou utilizando o wordpress e bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Inverta a ordem de referência das classes:

```css
.icons-categ .category-noticias {
    background: #e07737;
    color:#fff;
}

.icons-categ .category-celebridades {
    background: #1865e4;
    color:#fff;
}

.icons-categ .category-musicas {
    background: #aa0909;
    color:#fff;
}

.icons-categ .category-filmes {
    background: #b6e037;
    color:#fff;
}
```